# Why are only some portions of the EM spectrum able to pass through a metal dog bowl?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, experimental-physics, home-experiment

[image]

In this photo you can see part of the bowl, which I turned upside down and placed on top of various electromagnetic sources to determine whether the waves could pass through it. The graph in the background illustrates my results.

For the shorter wavelengths, I had to guess. I knew that ultraviolet would be blocked, but I assumed that x-rays and gamma rays could  go through the bowl.

To me, is seems that wavelengths in the range of, say, 100nm to 900nm are more easily stopped by the bowl. Even though I used a metal bowl, I think a plastic or paper bowl would produce similar results.

So my question is: **why are the waves in the middle of the spectrum  stopped by the bowl and not those at the ends?**

Here are some of the items I used in my experiment:
a TV Remote, a Bluetooth device, an IPhone, our Home WiFi, a Cellular LTE, a Sprinkler Remote, and a Radio.

All of the items on my list were able to pass through the bowl except the TV remote, which I assume was infrared.

Comment: Radio waves and microwaves will NOT pass "through a dog bowl", if it is made, as it appears, from aluminium or any other conductive material.

Comment: It does.  The cell phone works under the metal bowl. Try it.

Comment: Stream music or any other sound onto your phone from a wifi network. Wrap the phone in aluminum foil, one layer, and it will still work well beyond buffering time.

Comment: I did the demo this morning in my lecture - the same one I do every year.  A mobile phone does not work (will not receive phone calls) when wrapped in aluminium foil.  Ditto a radio wrapped in a single sheet of aluminium foil. Do the Math.

Comment: I just tried your streaming experiment. The problem is that I find a song will play all the way through, even if I turn the wifi off. Just tried again in my office with a phone call, and the foil blocks it fine.

Comment: @RobJeffries: My impression is, in the OP's question, long-wavelength radiation does not pass "through" the bowl, but it could pass around it, due to diffraction.

Comment: it passes under the bowl... You have to realize the extreme optimization of the channel capacity that is engineered into modern cellphones. They do a lot even in unfavourable conditions.

Comment: @RobJeffries is correct that it will not pass through the metal. Probably what is happening is that you were not creating a perfect Faraday cage. (If you place a phone on a counter and place a metal bowl over that, it won't stop the EM waves. That's because  while the metal dog bowl can stop the waves, the counter can't. Basically, you just create a shielded hemisphere, which would defeat the purpose of the experiment. Remember: EM waves can also be reflected around. Your experiment has to account for that.)

Comment: @RobJefferies, The music still plays without issues because your phone saves the song to a cache. That way, it can avoid network lag by always being a few songs ahead of the one you're listening to. (At least for streaming music.)

Comment: @CoilKid I know what a cache is. I pointed out the flaw in this particular experiment in my comments above.

Comment: @RobJeffries: I did not ascribe to you something that you did not write. I just had an impression that you doubted the OP's "experimental results", and the OP insisted on the results. So I was trying to say that there is no direct contradiction between your statement and the OP's results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Long-wavelength and short-wavelength radiation passes for different reasons: long-wavelength does not actually pass, but bends around the bowl due to diffraction (or is reflected from the walls), as the wavelength is greater or of the order of the dimensions of the bowl, and short-wavelength radiation passes because its frequency is higher than the plasma frequency of the metal of the bowl. Plastic and paper can give very different results (for example, in the visible range, if the plastic is transparent).

Comment: I awarded this answer my bounty because time was out and it was the only answer.  The visible portion of the spectrum appears to be the easiest to stop, but it's still not clear to me why.

Comment: @Lambda: as I said in the answer: because the visible light cannot pass directly through the bowl (its frequency is lower than the plasma frequency of the metal of the bowl) and cannot  pass around it using diffraction (as its wavelength is much less than the dimensions of the bowl).

Comment: @Lambda: You asked: "Is there a formula that explains how "durable" an electromagnetic wave is?" It's difficult to write down all the relevant formulas here: propagation of electromagnetic waves is a complex phenomenon. Some of the aspects of this phenomenon are plasma frequency, diffraction, skin-effect. You may wish to look them up.